# LINQ: Can't filtering List<Model> data by .Contains

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics, lambda

I have five Models (tables). I want to select all trainings which Venue_Distrcit is accessible by user whose ID is 1. But I prefer if can be solved with .Contains like firstTrainingSet. Also I have practiced with .Foreach but can't fix the proper format.

```
1. TRAINING                           2. TRAINING_VENUE              3. DISTRICT
   | ID | NAME | VENUE_ID |              | ID | NAME | DCODE |          | DCODE | NAME |

4. TRAINING_USER                      5.TRAINING_USER_DISTRICT_MAPPING
   |ID | NAME |                         | ID | USER_ID | DCODE|

var TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST = 
(from trainingUserDistrictMappingTable in db.TRAINING_USER_DISTRICT_MAPPING
where (trainingUserDistrictMappingTable.TRAINING_USER_ID  == 1)
select trainingUserDistrictMappingTable).ToList();

var trainingSet = db.TRAINING.Where(x => TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST.DCODE
         .Contains(x.TRAINING_VENUE.DCODE));
```

Here I need trainingSet. And x.TRAINING_VENUE.DCODE means that x is TRAINING parameter and x.TRAINING_VENUE can be fetched because  VENUE_ID of TRAINING table is foreign key from VENU table ID, and x.TRAINING_VENUE.DCODE is DOCDE from venue table. Which is actually primary key of DISTRICT table. TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST is list from DISTRICT table. The thing I can not do is TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST.DCODE.Contains(x.TRAINING_VENUE.DCODE).

Comment: I think problem is that you did not override Equals method in your models so that Contains method will compare fields but not references

Comment: @Toddams thanks. but i do not want to override model with = signs. I just here want to compare model.field with another same type value.

Comment: You can implement IEquatable<T> for each of your models without overriding  "=" operator

Comment: "Also making error" doesn't tell us anything about what that error is. It would be much easier to help you if you would provide a [mcve].

Comment: When I am selecting select trainingUserDistrictMappingTable.DCODE that is ok but when only model select trainingUserDistrictMappingTable then can  not use .Contains in the model listed data

Comment: Is `TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST2.DCODE` a `List<Model>` or another type? And What is the type of `TRAINING_VENUE.DISTRICT_ID`?

Comment: yes that fetched value from db . Defined in the upper line.

Comment: @JonSkeet please now see the question again. I need to check  TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST and compare it with training_venue.DCODE bu can't go in the right way.

Comment: There's still no [mcve], no sign of the class structure etc. I'm finding it hard to understand your description - a short but complete example including sample data and expected results would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: You need to use a join statement since the two tables don't have any common columns.  See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b#content

Comment: But previousle (please see before edit in this question) I did it with contain when selected table.column but when I have selected table now can't check it. This is the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet please see at the bottom line I have edited the requirements.

Comment: But *still* no [mcve] with sample data, class structures etc. You have ignored what I've asked for several times. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST` is collection so the expression should be:

```
var trainingSet = db.TRAINING
    .Where(x => TRAINING_USER_ACCESSIBLE_DISTRICT_LIST
               .Any(y => y.DECODE == x.TRAINING_VENUE.DCODE));
```

This will fix your issue.